# Is code after header("Location: ...) executed?

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

```
$_SESSION["some_value"] = 4;
header("Location: another-file.php");
$_SESSION["some_value"] = 5;
```

what's the value of `$_SESSION["some_value"]` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should always die() or exit() after the redirect (or as pointed out by Mark B, use ignore_user_abort() ) because you can't otherwise know for certain what will happen.

Though some code will get executed after a header location redirect, it's important to note that not all code after it will necessarily get executed.

As per your example, yes, some_value will equal 5. But at some point the script will get prematurely terminated.

Take the following example:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["some_value"] = 'original value';
header("Location: /index.php/test2");

$start_time = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i <= 100000; $i ++)
{
    password_hash($i);  // slow it down
    $_SESSION["some_value"] = $i;   
    $_SESSION['time'] = microtime(true) - $start_time;
}

$_SESSION['some_value'] = 'finished!';
```

If all the other answers were correct, you'd assume $_SESSION['some_value'] would equal 'finished!' -- but I ran the code and this is not the case.

Here are my results:

```
some_value: 174
time: 0.0026998519897461
```

Trial two:

```
some_value: 218
time: 0.0033109188079834
```

Trial three:

```
some_value: 218
time: 0.0035371780395508
```

Trial four:

```
some_value: 174
time: 0.0026431083679199
```

Trial five:

```
some_value: 174
time: 0.0027921199798584
```

If I implement ignore_user_abort(TRUE); in the above script then some_value does equal "finished!" so keep that in mind if you intend to do something critical like logging or database queries or sending emails after the redirect.

Comment: An excellent, and very informative answer - if only more were like this I have now accepted it over the previously accepted answer (I hope that the poster won't mind; it's not like he needs the points ;-). Thanks

Answer (score 27):

The value is 5.

You can output a lot more headers than just `Location` headers with `header`, most of which you don't want to stop your code execution. If you want to stop code execution, you need to call `exit` explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

Once you issue the header, you've started a race between your code and the webserver/browser. Generally, as soon as the browser receives the redirect, it'll close the connection that ran the script and start connecting to the new redirect URL. When the connection's closed, the web server will generally try to kill the script.

You might get lucky and be able to finish off anything else you wanted to do, or your might be unlucky and the script won't even be able to reach the next line after the `header()` call.

There is the [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function, which should let your script continue regardless of the connection's status, though.

Comment: No, it still downloads the entire response, even if it has a location header. That's why you need to call `exit;` after the header if you want it to redirect without executing any more code. If it was random whether or not it executed the remaining code then that wouldn't be a very useful feature, would it?

Comment: it wouldn't be a feature. it would just be a funny little bug to remind you that browsers work that way. of course, they don't.

Comment: @TorValamo I'm not sure that's entirely accurate. I've been working on a project where I set the location header without exiting afterwards, and locally, the code afterwards did not execute, whereas when it was pushed to a dev server for testing the code was being executed!

Comment: @billyonecan I believe that has to do with configuration of the php engine. It's always better to go with the restrictive option when that is actually what you want. Rather than hope that the dev server has the restriction in place already.

Answer (score 2):

The `header` command doesn't interrupt the flow of your code. Even if that is encountered, your page is still downloaded by the browser, even if it isn't show. Consider 404 pages, which (despite being errors) are still processed by the browser (though they are rendered while redirects are not).

Answer (score 1):

of course 5. You have to add exit() after such a header.