# Not being logged in in php , please check my code

Tags: php

why I insert to login its not getting login ,I am trying it on dashboard , by ajax and it is going to second php  and it is not working , when I insert wrong input it shows error "please check your username and password" but when I insert right input .. it shows nothing ,please check my code

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM main WHERE admin_email='$email' AND admin_password='$password'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!mysqli_fetch_array($query) > 0) {
    echo "Please Check your username and password";
    return false;
    exit;
}
else {

    header("location:admin_dashboard.php");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $_SESSION['main'] = $row;

    if (!$query) {
        printf("error:" . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
```

Comment: Output seems to depend on admin_dashboard.php. The problem might be in there.

Comment: You are setting `$_SESSION` after header. I think thats the problem

Comment: Please also show your `admin_dashboard.php` code too

Comment: you have a typo mistake in your code, change this to  header("Location:admin_dashboard.php");

Comment: Also you are writing code after this which never executes

Comment: admin_dashboard.php is just a simple page there is not in there

Comment: @Satya have you put `session_start()` at the top of your pages?

Comment: yes @ZainFarooq  i put if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();
}

Comment: just try put `session_start();` right after php tag

Answer (score 0):

php `mysql_fetch_array()` function always returns an array, check the docs here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php. So your condition might be wrong here. use like this

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM main WHERE admin_email='$email' AND admin_password='$password'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (count(mysqli_fetch_array($query)) > 0) {
    echo "Please Check your username and password";
    return false;
    exit;
}
else {

    header("Location:admin_dashboard.php");

    //this code will never execute as the page is redirected to admin_dashboard.php
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $_SESSION['main'] = $row;

    if (!$query) {
        printf("error:" . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `$_SESSION` variable after `header`. Sometimes it terminates to execute code after [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693537/is-code-after-headerlocation-executed). So you need to set `$_SESSION` before `header` to avoid terminating your code after `header`. Change your code like here

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$_SESSION['main'] = $row;
header("Location:admin_dashboard.php");
```

And in `admin_dashboard.php` page you need to check if your `$_SESSION['main']` has been set

```
if(isset($_SESSION['main']))
  {
     //You are logged in
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

have you pasted this text in the beginning:

```
$host = "your host";
$dbusername = "your username";
$dbpassword = "your password";
$dbname = "your database name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
```